# Is there a way of finding out where a particular CSS style is used on a website?

Tags: html, css

I know there are resources to check styles on a particular page, and others to clear out unused CSS but I need to make an amend to an existing style.

Before I do so I want to know if it will have an impact elsewhere on my website.

I am using Sitecore CMS (in case that is relevant).

Comment: Your question is a little broad... you are trying to amend css to existing style, you mean, to a css class or to a specific element? There is a way to show us an example of what you want to achieve or to modify? Are you using Javascript?

Comment: I have a CSS class that has a fixed px width on it which I want to change to a % (so it scales better) but I know this style may be used elsewhere on my site so I want to find out where else it is used so that I can check this won't break things on another page.

Comment: btn-secondary-long {
    width: 330px;         
    text-align: center;
    background: #01B0E9;
}

Comment: btn-secondary-long {
    width: 100%;         
    text-align: center;
    background: #01B0E9;
}

Comment: ok, I got it... well, the best way to do that, is adding inline style css, that always prevails over the classes from stylesheets... so you can go in your element that you want to change it, and add: style="width: 50%" for example... or with javascript you can add it dynamically

Comment: this is the best I can think for now, maybe the user below with the answer can help you better

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think I'll go with the TamperMonkey suggestion, but appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

The best to do it is to

- Inspect the element.
- If it is temporary, simply add it in the `element.style` in the dev tools.
- If not, select it with the highest precision you can

**What does this mean ?**

It means you need to use the longest css selector possible.

let's take an example :

```
<body>
  <nav></nav>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="article">
      <button></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

If you want to select the button and be sure not to touch anything else, you will to use this selector :

```
body > nav+div.content > div.article > button {}
```

Because of how CSS works, the last style applied is the most specific one.

Comment: Thanks, but this will lead to unnecessary additional styles, the site I work on is quite substantial so these add up to some very messy style sheets. 
What I'd much rather do is find out where else it is used.

Comment: If you want to find out where it's used, you can use this specific selector with `document.querySelectorAll(selector)`, this will return you every element using this style. Otherwise I'm sorry, but I don't get what you're trying to do here.

Comment: That will work on a page but I don't think I can use this across a whole website. What I'm trying to do is amend an existing style (change a width from px to %) which should be fine but I want to see where else it is used on the site to make sure. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Well if you want to detect something across a whole website, you won't do it with only css and a little bit of javascript ... What is your goal exactly ?

Comment: I'm not trying to use CSS to do it, I wanted to find a tool that will allow me to see where on a site a particular css style is used, then when I make my change (change a width from px to %) which should be fine but I want to see where else it is used on the site to make sure.I can check it hasn't thrown things out where that style is used elsewhere. I know there are tools that can help clear up unused css I was hoping there might be one to show me where a particular style is used across a site.

Comment: Oh okay ! well you can use tamperMonkey to launch a script that will replace the property you want in the class you want, using `document.styleSheets` to find your class.

Comment: Great, I don't need to replace anything at this stage, just find out where the style is used. I'll investigate tamper monkey - thank you very much.

Comment: But again, tamperMonkey will only work on your current page, if you want to explore a whole website, you will have to use a crawler, and on this I won't be able to help you, sorry !